# How to install bluetooth to Eeebox

Tags: bluetooth, eeebox

I need BT in my Eeebox, but didn't want it as an USB based device.

Tried to replace my mini-PCI wireless card with a mini-PCI AR5B225 card with integrated BT, but it requires a real hacker to make it work.

What are my best options to bring BT to this hardware?

Comment: Are you running Windows or Linux on it?

Comment: @Goblinlord, I use Ubuntu generally, but I tried Windows also. No result.